# Erroneous editor errors in VS 2015 ASP.Net MVC project with an area?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, visual-studio-2015

I  have an ASP.Net MVC project that I have an "Area" in. The area is called "Admin". I am also using  Ed Charbeneau's extremely useful prototyping HTML Helper to insert Lorem Ipsum placeholder text and pictures.

To make things a little simpler I have added

```
 <add namespace="Prototyping.Ipsum" />
 <add namespace="Prototyping.Placeholdit"/>
```

to the web.config in the view folder of the main section of the site so that the editor's error checking doesn't show rd squiggles when I put

```
@Html.Ipsum().p(4)
```

in the razor page. This works.

Now I have added an area to the project. I put the same namespace lines in the web.config in the view folder in my area but VS2015 insists on putting red squiggles under all the lines in my area's views.

The page still runs properly and all but the OCD part of me wants to get ride of the red squiggles and the inquisitive side of me wants to know why it is doing that in the area but not in the main site?

Comment: did you try closing all of the views and reopening them?

Comment: No, didn't think of the simple things.  That did it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As JamieD suggested. Closed view files and reopened and all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Except...if you reopen the files the red squiggles come back.
Is this a bug in VS 2015?

--NOTE: I know this isn't an answer, but I couldn't add a comment.

Comment: I just did a test creating an MVC project with an EF database reference in Visual Studio 2013. It built and ran fine. No squiggles. --- THEN I opened up the exact same project in VS 2015, opened a view and like noted, the red squiggles appeared. -- Builds succeed, and the project runs but the squiggles remain.